# Rails rendering JSON causing helper method to be called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm getting strange behavior when I render JSON from my Rails app. A helper method is run twice when `render :json` is called. Here's the controller and method:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def current
      render json: { :errors => "Incorrect credentials" }, :status => :bad_request
  end
end
```

I have the following helper module, with a `puts` statement for debugging:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def current_user
    puts "current_user"
    if encrypted_id = request.headers[:user_id]
      user = User.find_by(id: EncryptionService.decrypt(encrypted_id))
      if user && user.authenticated?(request.headers[:remember_token])
        @curent_user = user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The SessionsHelper is included in the Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

When sent the request, I get the following:

```
Started GET "/user/current" for ::1 at 2021-02-12 22:06:47 -0800
Processing by UsersController#current as */*
  Parameters: {"user"=>{}}
current_user
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.06ms)
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 6.6ms | Allocations: 383)
```

`current_user` was printed, even though the function was never called. When I comment out the `render json:` statement, leaving:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def current
  end
end
```

I get the following:

```
 Started GET "/user/current" for ::1 at 2021-02-12 22:09:43 -0800
Processing by UsersController#current as */*
  Parameters: {"user"=>{}}
Completed 204 No Content in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms | Allocations: 78)
```

`current_user` is not printed. Why would `render json:` call `current_user`? In my actual application, this is causing the database to be hit twice (although Rails wisely caches the result).

UPDATE: I'm onto something here. I ran `puts caller[0]` to see who was calling the function. The result:
`/Users/izaguirrejoe/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/active_model_serializers-0.10.12/lib/action_controller/serialization.rb:40:in 'serialization_scope'`

```
    def serialization_scope
      return unless _serialization_scope && respond_to?(_serialization_scope, true)

      send(_serialization_scope)
    end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a typo - `@curent_user` instead of `@current_user`. While its not likely the cause of your issue here you're gonna trip on it soon. You should also [use memoization](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/) to avoid sending a database query to look up the user every time the `current_user` method is called.

Comment: Thanks max, I just caught the misspelling moments before you pointed it out. Also great tip about the memoization, will return current_user if already set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you are using active_model_serializers, if you check out their docs it says [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md#controller-authorization-context), the default serialisation scope is `:current_user`. It also emphasizes that

> IMPORTANT: Since the scope is set at render, you may want to customize it so that current_user isn't called on every request. This was also a problem in 0.9.

This causes that the `current_user` method is always invoked. If you want to avoid this behaviour, you can set the `serialization_scope` in the controller for example:

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  serialization_scope nil # also you can pass a custom method here

  def current
    render json: { :errors => "Incorrect credentials" }, :status => :bad_request
  end
end
```

or in some cases only by calling `self.class.serialization_scope nil`.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up just dropping active model serializer entirely, Rails 6 handles it out of the box for the most part.